# Is there a way to put newlines in pysvg?

Tags: python, svg

Consider the following minimum working example:

```
from pysvg.text import *
from pysvg.builders import *

doc = svg()
doc.addElement(text("hello\nWorld", 150, 50))
doc.save('HelloWorld2.svg')
```

When the resulting svg **is viewed graphically**, the newline has been transformed into a single space, because the XML does not respect the newline.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  >
<text font-size="12" y="50" x="150"  >
hello
World</text>
</svg>
```

**How can I get a newline to display in the SVG?**

Comment: It _is_ a newline. Do you mean that you want a literal `\n`?

Comment: @sshashank124, Clarification: If you load the svg in firefox, you will see a single space instead of the newline in the XML. I want to see a newline in the actual image view of the SVG.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Section 10.1 of the SVG spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#Introduction) gives three options:

> Each ‘text’ element causes a single string of text to be rendered. SVG
>   performs no automatic line breaking or word wrapping. To achieve the
>   effect of multiple lines of text, use one of the following methods:
>
> - The author or authoring package needs to pre-compute the line breaks and use multiple ‘text’ elements (one for each line of text).
> - The author or authoring package needs to pre-compute the line breaks and use a single ‘text’ element with one or more ‘tspan’ child
>     elements with appropriate values for attributes ‘x’, ‘y’, ‘dx’ and
>     ‘dy’ to set new start positions for those characters which start new
>     lines. (This approach allows user text selection across multiple lines
>     of text -- see Text selection and clipboard operations.)
> - Express the text to be rendered in another XML namespace such as XHTML embedded inline within a ‘foreignObject’ element. (Note:
>     the exact semantics of this approach are not completely defined at
>     this time.)