# How to do line breaking using svgwrite module?

Tags: python, svg

I am using svgwrite to create svg file, then it crate

```
import svgwrite
drawing = svgwrite.Drawing("vis.svg",(1000, 1000))
for (s_x, s_y), (e_x, e_y) in zip(start, end):
        drawing.add(drawing.line((s_x, s_y), (e_x,  e_y), stroke='#f0f76f', stroke_width=width))
drawing.save( )
```

[image]

What I want is that it can automatically generate with a line break. How can I add "\n" at the end of each line?

[image]

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512469/is-there-a-way-to-put-newlines-in-pysvg P.S.: Sorry, Could not add a comment.

Comment: Line breaks are something associated with text, not lines. I don't know what you're asking here.

Comment: I mean the text breaking. I add a multiple lines or circles and when I open the svg file with notepad, then I can better check each line or circle  with line breaking.

Comment: I doubt this can be done without modifying the `svgwrite` module. If that's not an option, then the next best thing would be to post-process the svg file. I believe they're basically text file in XML format.